# asp.net 1.1 duplicated submission entries

Tags: asp.net, duplicates

I've got an old framework 1.1 project with the following problem: if user submits a page then in database duplicated records might appear. This error repeats often but is not consistent: in most cases there are no duplicated entries but in some cases there can be upto 4 of them. We disable submit button with JavaScript after first submission.

May be this would be helpful: there is a session object used to store user inputs (which are submitted).

Any scenarios you can think of why duplicated records can happen?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you please post some relevant code? There could be many reasons why this happens but without more to go on it is hard to offer any real answers.

Comment: i need code may be you are calling the save function twice. Without code nothing can be assumed

Comment: sorry, I am not allowed to post the code and it is just too long to modify. But the code for user input submission is fairly straightforward. There is a submit button which calls "PageSubmit" method, data is read from input fields on page. There are no loops or retry attempts for data submission.

Comment: Not too sure anyone can really help you then - as far as I know there are no specific Framework bugs which would cause this so it has to be something in the code. Best bet is to debug/test until you can find the exact circumstances that cause the problem.

Comment: Hi Kevin, ok thank you for reply, will look further into this.

Comment: What javascript do you use to disable the submit button? Maybe the dupes come from users with browsers that the javascript to disable the submit button does not work. So they just click away, resubmitting every time.

Comment: @ShaiCohen it can be a JS problem, this is only "hope" i have now. I considered your scenario, but duplicates happened also by me, when JS is enabled.

Comment: Ah I see. Thinking outside of the box here, how about setting a flag in session that indicates if a record has been saved and preventing saving of info if the flag is set? Would that work?

Comment: @ShaiCohen I end up doing approximately this, thanks

Comment: @lekso should I add an answer so you can select as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that some mobile browsers ignored JavaScript that disabled submission button and users managed to resubmit form multiple times.

The easiest (?) solution to this is the following:

Create a table "SubmissionTokens" in database with two fields: Token (uniqueidentifier), DateCreated (DateTime). Then, when page with submission form loads, add a token to database and save "id" value in a hidden field on the same page. When user submits the form then read token from the hidden field and see if token exists in table SubmissionTokens. If it does exist then insert a new record with form data in the database and delete the token from SubmissionTokens. You can also use DateCreate field to expire tokens.

At work I implemented a bit different solution and just look for duplicated records in the database before inserting a new record. But this is because there is a specific requirement that user must be able to resubmit form if he clicks "back" in browser. In this case the SubmissionToken is already deleted and the first solution wouldn't work.